# Capricious date constants in stored proc call

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

It prints: `The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect` without a reason, when I try to call a stored proc with `DATE` parameters from another stored proc.

Strange thing, presence or absence of unused variables affects the result.

this fails:

```
--<ScriptOptions statementTerminator="^"/>
CREATE PROCEDURE MYTESTDATE2 ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE @FOO INTEGER;

    CALL MYTESTDATE1 (
'2014-07-30'                                    -- IN @DATE_OF_INSERT TIMESTAMP,             
);

END P1
^
```

This succeeds:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYTESTDATE2 ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE @FOO INTEGER;

    SET @FOO = NULL;

    CALL MYTESTDATE1 (
'2014-07-30'                                    -- IN @DATE_OF_INSERT TIMESTAMP,             
);

END P1
```

This succeeds too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYTESTDATE2 ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN ATOMIC
    CALL MYTESTDATE1 (
'2014-07-30'                                    -- IN @DATE_OF_INSERT TIMESTAMP,             
);

END P1
```

Comment: Why are you supplying a `DATE` if the parameter is defined as `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Why not? Shouldn't it implicitly convert it to TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Where does it say that it should?

Comment: @mustaccio - well, the documentation says that [`DATE` will be promoted to `TIMESTAMP`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008477.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-3-1&lang=en), so looks like it does.  iSeries versions don't let you _compare_ them, for whatever reason, but the assignments still auto-promote.  DB2 considers an ISO formatted string involiate, though, so I'd never expect it to complain about that format (if you pass in an actual cast `DATE` it shouldn't complain), so something else is going on.